# Problem gaining authorized access to a webserver using python urllib3

Tags: html, python-3.x, http, urllib3

I manage my stock portfolio, by accessing certain websites, one needs no
authorization ((americanbulls.com  ) and the other (tipranks.com) has a user:password account which my browser automatically provides (I guess either by its cache or some additional request/response).
I am developing a python program with urllib3  to scrape the data I want from these websites, by attempting to send the same requests as my browser. 
No problem with the first, but for the second I get a response code of 200 and  unexpected text , the same whether I make my request with or without my user;password authorization in my header. (Why didnt I get a 400 type response in that case?),. and the same again if I repeat the request (with authorization).
I am completely out of my depth here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Header I get back in response is:

```
     HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Fri, 17 Jul 2020 16:57:21 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '4264', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-store, max-age=1', 'Expires': 'Thu, 16 Jul 2020 16:57:21 GMT', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'Set-Cookie': 'TiPMix=14.1902322947002; path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=www.tipranks.com; Max-Age=3600, x-ms-routing-name=self; path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=www.tipranks.com; Max-Age=3600', 'X-Diagnostic-From-Cache': 'none', 'X-Diagnostic-Last-Index-Load': '07/17/2020 16:57:18', 'X-Diagnostic-Index-Load-Ver': '07/14/2020 08:29:08', 'Accept-Language': 'en', 'Request-Context': 'appId=cid-v1:2d079efc-434a-418f-bd63-996ea31fac64', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Request-Context', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge', 'X-Frame-Options': 'sameorigin', 'Strict-Transport-
```

Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'})

and the text:
200 b'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n\r\n  \r\n    \r\n      .hide-no-js {\r\n        display: none;\r\n      }\r\n\r\n      .no-opacity-no-js {\r\n        opacity: 1;\r\n      }\r\n    \r\n  \r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    <iframe\r\n      src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WMX37F&pageCategory=sports&visitorType=returning"\r\n      height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">\r\n  \r\n  \r\n    window.setTimeout(function () {\r\n      (function (w, d, s, l, i) {\r\n        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({\r\n          'gtm.start':\r\n            new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'\r\n        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\r\n          j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =\r\n            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);\r\n      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', "GTM-WMX37F");\r\n    }, 0);\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    if (window.location.port !== '80') window.**env** = 'dev';\r\n  \r\n  \r\n    window.appHash = '83844b7ab8a6963852d2';\r\n  \r\n\r\n  \r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.13.0/polyfill.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha384-vqdIZ/QLRwPCEuhZYvYR9a3IQPsfnOMePPc6ODEOeIZTqsZh3ox3KIp1osNKjcAw"\r\n    crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-alJnAKUY0Ruhf55K/C+sCyz6zaipGhl1kxuzDW3jtHk=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-zxLuhMQXy7QBCD8nJT0FQaZN2GBcdEL4zooi/jAmu60=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-4l+MLGOR7l/v3VuQiGgchPcP2mEDT/9zq+JTLqBdFL8=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.lite.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-BTdxYW4Q/a3Xudq+5aK+ucGpARRiPK8IrjcS5umC6nI=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-13JFytp+tj8jsxr6GQOVLCgcYfMUo2Paw4jVrnXLUPE=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.2.1/ReactRouter.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-J7pBqENhYJK54dGzFYvWbRUt53NcwU848aSgHjZNQp8=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-7/yoZS3548fXSRXqc/xYzjsmuW3sFKzuvOCHd06Pmps=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-CutOzxCRucUsn6C6TcEYsauvvYilEniTXldPa6/wu0k=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-slick/0.23.2/react-slick.min.js"\r\n    integrity="sha256-/9bZi7b3Fa1NoSR9w6cUPmVXoKVL0LXl8Z86X05sjBk=" crossorigin="anonymous">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'
HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Fri, 17 Jul 2020 16:57:21 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '4264', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-store, max-age=1', 'Expires': 'Thu, 16 Jul 2020 16:57:21 GMT', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'Set-Cookie': 'TiPMix=14.1902322947002; path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=www.tipranks.com; Max-Age=3600, x-ms-routing-name=self; path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=www.tipranks.com; Max-Age=3600', 'X-Diagnostic-From-Cache': 'none', 'X-Diagnostic-Last-Index-Load': '07/17/2020 16:57:18', 'X-Diagnostic-Index-Load-Ver': '07/14/2020 08:29:08', 'Accept-Language': 'en', 'Request-Context': 'appId=cid-v1:2d079efc-434a-418f-bd63-996ea31fac64', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Request-Context', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge', 'X-Frame-Options': 'sameorigin', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'})

Comment: What type of authorization does the website support? Can you share an example header and body of your request? Also, have you tried recording the header and body of your request and its response when you login using your browser? If so, can you share that too? Finally, try using Postman (https://www.postman.com) to get things right and then have it create you a python script and start from there. Postman handles lots of tasks automatically and can reflect those in the code snippet it creates. The free version should suffice your need.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to post my request (user:passwd altered) and the response from the website ( I don't understand what it is telling me) in my original question. I don't know how to record my browser's conversation.  As you suggest  I'll have a go at postman next.

Comment: have now  looked at the website's response in my browser, it is asking for my id and password,so knows I am not my usual browser, despite me sending same header.   I  am reluctant to go further trying to continue the conversation with the website, handling redirects, or whatever.